# installing gcovr on ubuntu using pip

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, gcovr

I am trying to intall gcovr on ubuntu using

```
pip install gcovr
```

but it gives this error

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_mymachine/gcovr/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uqjIdg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_mymachin/gcovr
```

Storing debug log for failure in /home/mymachin/.pip/pip.log

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it with `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

I had no problems installing it this way:

```
sudo pip install gcovr
```

No errors.

If you're on Ubuntu 14.04, you may need to upgrade your pip.

```
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Comment: @double_j Hi, I tried `sudo pip install gcovr`, I get a different error now `Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/` any ideas?

Comment: i would try to install pip without apt-get if your on ubuntu.